# Present ng-repeat values in separate <td> for each data stored in array. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

The values of array sent from backend has to be separated and to be present in different rows when using ng-repeat. I have an array that gets data from database however it saves all the data in the first index.

Backend

```
List <String> sportsValues;
```

Angular JS

```
$scope.sports = { values: [] }; 

if (scope.sports.values.length > 0) {
 $scope.sports.values.push(sportsValues)
};
```

HTML

```
<table> 
 <tr ng-repeat="value in sports.values">
     <td> {{ values }} </td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

Current Result

```
[["football, basketball, baseball"]]
```

If I do, `$scope.sports.value(0) = {"football, basketball, baseball"}`

Desired result in a table

```
football
basketball
baseball
```

People suggested join, list separator in CSS and split but none of them worked. 
A simple guide or tips would be grateful.

Comment: Well, you have a 2D array... do you want a 2D array? `$scope.sports.values = sportsValues` would work as well.

Comment: @tymeJV,  No, I just want a simple array that can present the data in different <td> in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just print first instance then

```
<table> 
  <tr ng-repeat="value in sports.values[0]">
     <td> {{ value }} </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

You want to print all the values in each `tr`, then simply you need to change the way how you're assigning value to `$scope.sports.values`

```
$scope.sports = { values: [] }; 

if(angular.isArray(sportsValues)) {
   $scope.sports.values = sportsValues[0].split(",");
}
```

then change `ng-repeat` to what you had before

```
<table> 
  <tr ng-repeat="value in sports.values">
     <td> {{ value }} </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to tweak the code where each value will get their each td?

Comment: @JohnSmith is the collection is gonna have multiple values like `[["a","b","c"], ["d","e", "f"]...]`?

Comment: It is ["a, c, d, e, f, g"]

Comment: @JohnSmith then instead of `$scope.sports.values.push(sportsValues)` line just do `$scope.sports.values = sportsValues` where you;re assigning result array to values & then `ng-repeat="value in sports.values"`

Comment: Parker, Sorry to say but now I get a, c, d, e, f, g

Comment: @JohnSmith my bad I overlooked your last comment, it should be `$scope.sports.values = sportsValues.split(",")`(make sure you don't have space in `sportsValues` value like `["a,c,d,e,f,g"]`)

Comment: Firebug warns, Error: sportsValues.split is not a function